# Does Implementing Lambda Expressions in Java Enhance Code Efficiency?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Does incorporating lambda expressions in Java enhance the efficiency of our code? Could someone elaborate on this?

Lambda expressions are known to boost code readability and decrease the need for interpretation. Besides these advantages, are there other benefits of using lambda expressions in Java in our programming practices?

Comment: "*... and do not require interpretation*" - What do you mean by this? They need as much or as less interpretation as everything else. the mapping from syntax to semantics is a bijunction, and explained in the language specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Lambdas allows you to write concise code.
2. It encourages the use of functional programming.
3. It simplifies variable scope and encourages code reusability.
4. Lambdas allows you to use parallel processing.

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe**. If you are performing an "embarrassingly parallelizable" operation in a `parallelStream()`. But that is not the primary purpose of lambda expressions, they are usually described in terms of abstract classes, but the actual implementation involved the introduction of the `invokedynamic` bytecode instruction; that involves dynamically determining the correct method to invoke at runtime. That resolution process is one time, but it is an expense. If your operation can be amortized over time, you can discount it; but the expense exists.